# Action creator's asynchronous code causing error

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, redux

I'm using axios to do a post in my action creator. My action creator takes in an array of objects and posts it to an express server.

I'm trying to set the payload to be the response of the server but I realize that the response occurs after the action has been created.

```
export function sendOrders (data : Order[] ){
 console.log("gets inside sendOrders action creator")
 var output : string;
 axios.post('http://localhost:8081/', data)
 .then(function (response) {
   output = response.data;
   console.log(output)
 })
 .catch(function (error) {
   output = error;
   console.log(output)
 });

 return {
     type: SEND_ORDERS,
     payload : output 
 }
}
```

As a result, my reducer returns "undefined". Does anyone know how I can work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Action creators are *synchronous*. That being said, there are redux plugins, like `redux-thunk` and `redux-saga` that allow an action creator to be asynchronous, which would let you emit an action after the Promise completes.

Example using redux-thunk:

```
export function sendOrders (data : Order[]) { 
  return (dispatch) => {
    var output : string;
    return axios.post('http://localhost:8081/', data)
      .then(function (response) {
        output = response.data;
        console.log(output)

        dispatch({
          type: SEND_ORDERS,
          payload: output 
        });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        output = error;
        console.log(output)
      });
  };
}
```

So essentially, your action creator returns a Promise-returning function which is passed `dispatch` and `getState` so you can asynchronously read state and dispatch actions. In order to use this example, you have to add the plugin. From the sample in the documentation:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';

// Note: this API requires redux@>=3.1.0
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
```